# Random integer shifting

Tags: c#

I have a problem with my shifting. I have an array of integers. There are always 3 integers in the array. I pass these integer in the array into a sorter. I want to randomly shift these integers. Example: I pass integer 1, 2, 3 in the array. I want it to randomize and return values 1, 2, 3 in a random order. It does randomize but when i call the function three times in a row it returns the integers in the same order type.

Example: I call the function 3 times. [1, 2, 3] [4, 5, 6] [7, 8, 9]
When it sorts it always returns the integers arranged in the same order.
Like this [2, 1, 3] [5, 4, 6] [8, 7, 9]
I want it to return those pairs randomly not in some type of order.

Here is my code.

```
    private Array returnRandomInts(int[] i)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int c = 0;
        int r = rand.Next(10);
        int prev = 0;
        int current = 0;
        int temp;

        while (c < r)
        {
            current = rand.Next(0, 3);
            if (current != prev)
            {
                temp = i[prev];
                i[prev] = i[current];
                i[current] = temp;
                c++;
            }
        }

        return i;
    }
```

Here is how i call it

```
        returnRandomInts(index);
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + index[0].ToString() + " " + index[1].ToString() + " " + index[2].ToString() + ", ";
```

They are always in a certain order. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'd add some debug statements to print out the values of `r` and `current`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are always creating a new `Random` instance when the function is invoked.  This uses a time-dependent seed.  If you are calling the function 3 times in quick succession, it is likely to be seeded with the same value, and so you will get the same pseudo-random sequence.

Instead of instantiating `Random` in the function, make `rand` a class member variable and initialise it once in the class constructor.  That way, it will be seeded only once and will deliver a proper pseudo-random sequence.

Comment: Oo that is good to know. Can you tell me how to fix it please ?

Comment: That worked Perfect thank you very much. Will accept answer when it lets me.